# Email -- what is the correct to wrap the "a href" link in email message?

Tags: php, email

I am trying to set the mail body to display the links in email for the user to download pdf in case if they need to download again in future. It is not html body as it doesn't work on most email showing html codes. So I decide on plain text for email instead.

```
  $umessage .='<a href="'.home_url('/download.php?f=pdffiles/'.$filename).'"><a href="'.home_url('/download.php?f=pdffiles/'.$filename).'">'.$title.'</a>';
       }}
```

What is wrong with single quotes? It displays in email:

```
<a href="http://localhost/download.php?..............">file name</a>
```

I don't think double quote will help, right?

**EDIT #2**

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"
```

seems that it won't work well in any email application except apple mail.

Any idea on that or maybe it is incorrect?

**EDIT #3**

```
$umessage = "Thank you for downloading pdf. \r\n\r\n";
        $umessage .=    "Please click on the link below to download\r\n";
          if(count($selectfiles)>0)
        {
            foreach($selectfiles as $key)
            {
                $keyArray = explode('@',$key);

                $filename = $keyArray[1];

                $title = $keyArray[0];

      $umessage .='<p>Download '. '<a href="'.home_url('/download.php?f=pdffiles/'.$filename).'"><a href="'.home_url('/download.php?f=pdffiles/'.$filename).'">'.$title.'</a></p>';

}}

        $fm ='xxxx';
        $to='xxx';

        $subject = "Download Request from ". $name;
        $headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; 
        $headers .= 'From:<'.$fm.'> ' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $to;

        $uto      = $email;
        $usubject = "Thank you for Downloading our PDF";

        wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        wp_mail($uto, $usubject, $umessage, $headers);
```

Comment: I don't think you can put a html link in a plain text file. Some email readers might convert it tho.

Comment: most users do use a html supporting email client now, i would say 90%+

Comment: @AlixAxel - code is added in Edit #3

Answer (score 2):

If you're sending the email as plain text, then any HTML formatting you send will be displayed as plain text. It's as simple as removing the html formatting from your email

```
$umessage .= 'download link: '.home_url('/download.php?f=pdffiles/'.$filename);
```

Comment: thank you. can i ask question? Why html format wouldn't be recognized in different email body like gmail or outlook? It would show html code: <table>example</table>

Comment: If you don't specify the content type of an email as html, then the content will be displayed as plain text aka the html will be shown as text. If you're sending an email has html, you need to ensure the header `Content-type: text/html;` is being correctly sent along with the html body.

Comment: i have $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n"; still can't read html properly

Answer (score 0):

Relative links only work in the context of a web page.  Within the email, a link of "/download.php?yadda" is meaningless, because there is no host to attach it to.

You can get around this by using full URLs within the links in email:

```
$umessage .='<a href="'.home_url('http://example.com/download.php?...
```

You MAY also be able to deal with this using a [`<base>` tag in your HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp), but that may not be interpreted properly by all email clients.  You'd need to test.